# Twitterカードの image:alt 設定を行うと、何が変わるのですか？

Tags: twitter

**試したこと1**
Twitterカードの summary_large_image で [twitter:image:alt](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/markup) 設定を行いました。

```
<meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="hoge">
```

HTML の alt にテキストが追加されると思ったのですが、altには何も追加されませんでした。
生成結果画像のHTML

```
<img alt="" draggable="true" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/card_img/xxxx/xxxx?format=jpg&amp;name=small" class="css-xxxx">
```

---

**試したこと2**
[[画像の説明を追加] 設定](https://help.twitter.com/ja/using-twitter/picture-descriptions)をオンにする必要があるのかと思い、試してみましたが、何も変わりませんでした

---

**Q**
Twitterカードの image:alt 設定を行うと、何が変わるのですか？

補足
・これ以外のカード設定は正常に反映されています
・「最初にやりたいことありき」ではなく、設定項目が用意されているのに期待した通り動作しないのはなぜだろう？ という質問です